# cakephp 3 - reference app model from plugin

Tags: cakephp, plugins, model, reference

I have a plugin that needs to access a model ( UsersRoles ) from the main app.

Looking at the debugger I got this :

> *Generated Models The following Table objects used Cake\ORM\Table instead of a concrete class:
>       UsersRoles*

The warning seems to be produced by this statement ( plugin ) :

```
$userInfo = $this->Users->findById( $user['id'] )
              ->contain( [ 'UsersRoles' ] )
              ->first();
```

The `UsersRoles` table belongs to the main app.  The query is executed successfully, but the debug shows the warning.

Is there a way to reference the model from the main app from inside the plugin that makes the warning go out ?

Thanks.
Regards.
Facundo.

Comment: Plugins should be independent of the app so you shouldn't be doing this. Why are you trying to do this from within a plugin?

Comment: In this case, the plugin is trying to check a permission using the users and users roles from the main app.  From your explanation, I can imagine the plugin calling a method from the main app instead of accessing directly to the tables.  Is that correct ?.  Thanks.  Regards. Facundo.